# Transferring between airports in Oslo (Norway)

Tags: airports, transportation, airport-transfer, oslo

What is the quickest, cheapest and safest way to transfer from Moss Airport Rygge in Norway to Oslo Gardermoen airport and how long would it take?

Comment: Are you assuming there is a solution which is at once quickest, cheapest and safest, or are you asking three separate questions?

Comment: You have to provide more details. You can transfer fast and expensive by taxi, or slow and cheaper by bus or train. Bus and train schedules depends on which weekday and time you intend to travel.

Comment: Travelling on 01/11/16. Flight arrives in ryggge at 4:30pm. Travelling on a budget

Comment: When do you have to be at Gardermoen? If budget is a priority, why are you asking for the quickest transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Rome-2-Rio is very good for such questions: http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Moss-Airport-RYG/Oslo-Airport-Station

Train 24 $, Car 23 $, Bus 57 $

Comment: Thanks. I accidently booked to Rygga instead of Oslo International. Need to fly same day to Bergen Norway

Comment: The prices are very inaccurate. Both train and bus is about US$ 30.